# Load more button for table rows in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am using the following function to display a table for a wordpress plugin:

```
            <?php
            function display_table(){

            global $wpdb;

            echo '
            <table class="widefat">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <th>IMG</th>       
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <th>IMG</th>       
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>';
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '. $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
            $row = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
                foreach ( $row as $row ) 
                { 
                    echo '
               <tr>
                    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row->id .'"></td>';
                echo '<td><img src="/my_images/' . $row->my_file. '"</td>';
                 echo '<td>' . $row->title .'</td>
               </tr>';}
            echo '</tbody>
            </table>';
            ?>
```

I want to add a "Load More" button below the table as the table becomes quite large. Initially I would like to display 5 rows. How can I do this?

I found a tutorial and tried to adapt it, but it doesn't seem to work. Code below. Both "myplugin.php" and "more_rows.php" are in the same folder on the server.

The page "myplugin.php" :

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                var track_click = 0; 

                var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;
                $('#results').load("more_rows.php", {'page':track_click}, function() {track_click++;}); 

                $(".load_more").click(function (e) {

                    $(this).hide(); 
                    $('.animation_image').show(); 

                    if(track_click <= total_pages) 
                    {

                        $.post('more_rows.php',{'page': track_click}, function(data) {

                            $(".load_more").show(); 

                            $("#results").append(data);


                            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 500);


                            $('.animation_image').hide(); 

                            track_click++; 

                        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                            alert(thrownError); 
                            $(".load_more").show(); 
                            $('.animation_image').hide(); 
                        });


                        if(track_click >= total_pages-1)
                        {

                            $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                     }

                    });
            });
            </script>


            <?php
            function display_table(){

            global $wpdb;
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '. $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
            $item_per_page = 5;
            $get_total_rows = $wpdb->query($sql);
            $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows/$item_per_page);    

            ?>

            <div id="results"></div>

            <div align="center">
            <button class="load_more" id="load_more_button">load More</button>
            <div class="animation_image" style="display:none;"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"> Loading...</div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

And the page "more_rows.php":

```
                <?php
            $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

            if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
                header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
                exit();
            }

            $position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '. $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' . $position .',' . $item_per_page;
            $row = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

            echo '
                            <table class="widefat">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                    <th>IMG</th>       
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                    <th>IMG</th>       
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>';


                                foreach ( $row as $row ) 
                                { 
                                    echo '
                               <tr>
                                    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row->id .'"></td>';
                                echo '<td><img src="/my_images/' . $row->my_file. '"</td>';
                                 echo '<td>' . $row->title .'</td>
                               </tr>';}
                            echo '</tbody>
                            </table>';
                            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of lines: at the end of your query use the keyword "LIMIT".
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table where x=x limit 5
```

Then, if you are sure the table has more than 5 items, just add a link a href below the table by adding a GET parameter, example:

```
<a href="?load=all">load more</a>
```

And modify the query like this:

```
$limit = " LIMIT 5 ";
IF $_GET["load"] == "all" THEN
   $limit = "";
SELECT * FROM table where x=x $limit
```

Then you can also use ajax, or directly load all lines but hide all after the 5th line (with style display:hidden) and use javascript to show them once the user clicks on "load more".

It depends with what you want to do.
Have fun.